# Syntax error during jsonendecode() in Terraform

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, dictionary, terraform, aws-secrets-manager

here's my first bootle to the sea.

I want to create one single secret manager that contains a map of 3 passwords with Terraform IAC.
To do that, I have tried to create a aws_secretmanager_version with

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret_master" {
  name = "secret-master"
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "sversion" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_master.id
  secret_string = <<EOF
   {
    "dbPassword": "${random_password.db_password.result}",
    "awsSecretAccess": "${random_password.aws_access_key_id.result}",
    "secretAccessKey": "${random_password.sec_access_key.result}"
   }
EOF
}

data "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "secret_master" {
  arn = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_master.arn
}
 
data "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "secrets" {
  secret_id = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_master.id
}
 
locals {
  secrets = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets.secret_string)
}
```

In fact, i followed this tutorial to understand : https://automateinfra.com/2021/03/24/how-to-create-secrets-in-aws-secrets-manager-using-terraform-in-amazon-account/

The problem is the error resulting :

```
│
│   on sm.tf line 60, in locals:
│   60:   secrets = jsondecode(data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets.secret_string)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets.secret_string has a sensitive value
│
│ Call to function "jsondecode" failed: invalid character '"' after object key:value pair.
```

I replaced the random_passwords with strings "eeeee" and verified several times the json syntax. Nothing changed.

Could you help me to learn more about this error ?

Comment: Which terraform version are you using?

Comment: Terraform v1.1.7
on windows_386
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.20.1
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/random v3.3.2
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/template v2.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is saying that your string in `data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets.secret_string` does not have valid JSON syntax.

I have to assume that `data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.secrets.secret_string` is the same as `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.sversion.secret_string` here, but I'm not 100% sure since I'm not an expert on AWS secrets manager.

If that *is* true then I expect what's happening is that one of the strings that you interpolated into the JSON string contains a `"` character which is therefore causing the resulting string to not be valid JSON.

To guarantee that your result will be valid JSON, you should use [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsonencode) to produce that string instead of string template, because then Terraform will guarantee to generate valid JSON escaping for you when needed:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "sversion" {
  secret_id = aws_secretsmanager_secret.secret_master.id
  secret_string = jsonencode({
    dbPassword      = random_password.db_password.result
    awsSecretAccess = random_password.aws_access_key_id.result
    secretAccessKey = random_password.sec_access_key.result
  })
}
```

The above `secret_string` expression first constructs a *Terraform* object value, and then uses `jsonencode` to translate that into a string containing an equivalent JSON object, using the translation rules shown in the documentation for `jsonencode`.

---

This is tangential to your question, but note also that it's unnecessary and potentially problematic to read back the same object using a `data` block that this module is managing using a `resource` block.

In the example you showed is relatively harmless because Terraform can clearly see the dependency relationship between the `data` blocks and the `resource` blocks -- but unless these resource types are designed in a very unusual way all this is achieving is telling Terraform to read the same object it already had in memory anyway, which may cause you to hit rate limits faster or make your `terraform apply` slower.

You can refer directly to `jsondecode(aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.sversion.secret_string)` to use the value you assigned to that argument in other parts of the configuration, and so I would recommend doing that and not using the data blocks, unless you know that the data sources are doing some kind of transformation on that value that is important to your downstream use of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The "data." element should serve when my secret manager will add secret rotation to the service. It is useful to ask the current version of the password.